# Adjust width of listings including pagebreaks

Tags: xetex, listings, minipage

I have my own lstlistings environments which are framed. Since I wanted to adjust the width so the frame starts with the text I used a minipage inside the lstlisting.
(See MWE).

But as I have quite long code fragments I'd like to allow Page-Breaks inside the listing which is not possible using minipage.

I was not able to achieve the same thing using `\adjustwidth{..}`.

Any ideas? (I am using XeLatex)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[]{english}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\lstnewenvironment{example}[1]
  {
  \flushleft \textbf{Example }\def\ExampleDescription{#1\\}\\
  \ExampleDescription
  \hspace*{\dimexpr\fboxrule+\fboxsep}% 
  \minipage{\dimexpr\textwidth-\fboxsep-\fboxrule}% 
  }{
  \endminipage
  }
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-6]
\begin{example}{Description}
hello
this is a code example
that should
be long
enough
to provoke a pagebreak
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `minipage` is unbreakable. Why don't you just use the `linewidth` option of the listings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This doesn't really concern Xetex so I excluded that from my example.)

Sorry, I've misunderstood your question at first. A `minipage` is unbreakable by default, but you can use the `xleftmargin=3pt` and `xrightmargin=3pt` option of `lstlisting`. `3pt` comes from the default value of the `framesep` option. If you change it, change these too (it can be automatized, but it's huge overkill if you don't really need it).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single, xleftmargin=3pt, xrightmargin=3pt}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\lstnewenvironment{example}[1]
  {
  \flushleft \textbf{Example }\def\ExampleDescription{#1\\}\\
  \ExampleDescription
  \hspace*{\dimexpr\fboxrule+\fboxsep}%
  }{
  }
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-6]
\begin{example}{Description}
hello
this is a code example
that should
be long
enough
to provoke a pagebreak
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well the frame still goes outside the text-range... I tried that as well

Comment: @Kathiieee I misunderstood your question. Is it okay now?

Comment: it works perfectly, you saved my day :)

Comment: @Kathiieee You should give that an upvote then. ;)